# How do I get expected colors of a box shadow?

Tags: css, border, border-shadow

I have a psd image of a website, and I want to get same color code on a box shadow as it is displayed in the image.

For example:
Background color is: `#e6e6e6`
And the content inside is white.

I want to get box shadow that is 2px wide and insite. 
The first pixel from the right has color code:`#e3e3e3`

The second pixel has the color code: `#f1f1f1`

Experimenting with opacity and other settings takes time so is there any way to type these colors to get excpected result/colors?

Answer (score 1):

you could draw 2 shadows without blur, if i understand well: a 2 px shadow from 2 colors .

```css
div,
p {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e3e3e3, 0 0 0 2px #f1f1f1;
  Background: #e6e6e6;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px gray
}
p {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #e3e3e3, 2px 2px #f1f1f1;
}
/*awfull  body bg for demo*/

body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, purple, turquoise, tomato);
```

```html
<div>
  box
</div>
<p>
  or did you mean this ?
</p>
```